# How to update an array column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know we can replace values in a dataframe column and return a new dataframe with updated values using below method :

```
dataframe.withColumn("col1",when(col("col1").equalTo("this"),"that").otherwise(col("make")))
```

but this will change the whole column value wherever required.

Now I have a slightly complex dataframe:

```
|        colleagues|   name|

|[guy1, guy2, guy3]|Thisguy|
|[guy4, guy5, guy6]|Thatguy|
|[guy7, guy8, guy9]|Someguy|
```

Here I have a 'colleagues' column which holds arrays. And I want to replace a specific element of any array, e.g instead of 'guy2' in the first row I want 'guy10' in my new dataframe
How can I achieve that? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

There are a couple of questions to be answered before offering a final solution (e.g. the ordering of the elements in `colleagues` array after replacing some), but I don't want to drag this along too long. Let's have a look at the very common approach to solve problems like this.

### Solution

Since `colleagues` column is an array column (and Spark it very effective at queries over rows) you should first `explode` (or `posexplode`) it. With rows per array element you can do necessary changes and in the end `collect_list` to have the array column back.

> **explode(e: Column): Column**
> Creates a new row for each element in the given array or map column.
>
> **posexplode(e: Column): Column**
> Creates a new row for each element with position in the given array or map column.

Let's use the following `names` dataset:

```
val names = Seq((Array("guy1", "guy2", "guy3"), "Thisguy")).toDF("colleagues", "name")
scala> names.show
+------------------+-------+
|        colleagues|   name|
+------------------+-------+
|[guy1, guy2, guy3]|Thisguy|
+------------------+-------+
scala> names.printSchema
root
 |-- colleagues: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Let's `explode`, do the changes and in the end `collect_list`.

```
val elements = names.withColumn("elements", explode($"colleagues"))
scala> elements.show
+------------------+-------+--------+
|        colleagues|   name|elements|
+------------------+-------+--------+
|[guy1, guy2, guy3]|Thisguy|    guy1|
|[guy1, guy2, guy3]|Thisguy|    guy2|
|[guy1, guy2, guy3]|Thisguy|    guy3|
+------------------+-------+--------+
```

That's what Spark SQL can handle with ease. Let's use `regexp_replace` (What? regexp?! And now you've got two problems :)).

```
val replaced = elements.withColumn("replaced", regexp_replace($"elements", "guy2", "guy10"))
scala> replaced.show
+------------------+-------+--------+--------+
|        colleagues|   name|elements|replaced|
+------------------+-------+--------+--------+
|[guy1, guy2, guy3]|Thisguy|    guy1|    guy1|
|[guy1, guy2, guy3]|Thisguy|    guy2|   guy10|
|[guy1, guy2, guy3]|Thisguy|    guy3|    guy3|
+------------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

In the end, let's group by the initial array column and use `collect_list` grouping function.

```
val solution = replaced
  .groupBy($"colleagues" as "before")
  .agg(
    collect_list("replaced") as "after",
    first("name") as "name")
scala> solution.show
+------------------+-------------------+-------+
|            before|              after|   name|
+------------------+-------------------+-------+
|[guy1, guy2, guy3]|[guy1, guy10, guy3]|Thisguy|
+------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

### Alternative Solutions

#### User-Defined Function (UDF)

Alternatively, you could also write a custom user-defined function, but that would not benefit from as many optimizations as the solution above so I'd not recommend it (and will only show on request).

#### Custom Logical Operator

The best approach would be to write a custom logical operator (a [LogicalPlan](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/LogicalPlan.scala)) that would do all this and participate in optimizations, but avoid exchanges (introduced by `groupBy`). That'd however be a fairly advanced Spark development that I have not done yet.

Comment: solutions for withColumn(..., explode()) are clear. What about posexplode? 
your https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20174 has no updates so far.

Comment: nevermind, I found a way: `df selectExpr("*", "posexplode(s) as (p,c)") drop("s")`